# MySQLException when trying to connect to a database in visual studio: Cannot connect to Server. Contact Administrator

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio-2015

I try to connect to a mysql database in my windows application program, but I keep coming across a MySQLException, which goes with case 0 in Open Connection. And everything should be right. It could be that I'm wrong about the name of the server but it should be just localhost. Where could I check if the server name is right and if it is, what else could be causing this problem?

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PlantsClientServerApp
{
    public partial class AllPlants : Form
    {
        private string server;
        private string database;
        private string uid;
        private string password;
        private MySqlConnection connection;
        private MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter;

        public AllPlants()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void AllPlants_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            server = "localhost";
            database = "plants only";
            uid = "root";
            password = "K1326629ktcj5423";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from plants_database2", connection);
                DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];

                //close connection
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
          }


        private bool OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                //When handling errors, you can your application's response based on the error number.
                //The two most common error numbers when connecting are as follows:
                //0: Cannot connect to server.
                //1045: Invalid user name and/or password.
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server. Contact administrator");
                        break;
                    case 1045:
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                        break;
                    default:
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

        private bool CloseConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is the servername really localhost? or just local?

Comment: It should just be localhost but idk where I could confirm that exactly...

Comment: Nm I fixed it. Thanks anyways